# SSDT Unresolved Reference to Object

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I'm receiving a number of "unresolved reference to object" errors on a SQL Server Database Project I created in VS 2017.

These errors all point to the "sys." objects.

I have added a .dacpac reference from the master database, including generating a new .dacpac for the master database.

I've also tried adding references to the master database itself, with no luck.   I've also rebooted my machine, but that didn't help either.

I've tried the remedies listed in Stack Overflow, but none of those solutions have worked for me.  Any suggestions?   Here's an example of the errors I'm getting from the build:

```
SSISDB\internal\Views\current_user_object_permissions.sql(15,55): 
Error SQL71501: View: [internal].[current_user_object_permissions] contains an unresolved reference to an 
Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because 
it could refer to any of the following objects: [internal].[object_permissions].[pri]::
[name], [sys].[database_principals].[name] or [sys].[database_principals].[pri]::[name].
```

**Updated**

Sql:

```
CREATE VIEW [internal].[current_user_object_permissions] AS 
SELECT obj.[object_type], obj.[object_id], obj.[permission_type], obj.[sid], obj.[is_role], obj.[is_deny] 
FROM [internal].[object_permissions] AS obj 
INNER JOIN [sys].[database_principals] AS pri ON obj.[sid] = pri.[sid] 
WHERE ((pri.[type] = 'S' OR pri.[type] = 'U') AND obj.[sid] = USER_SID (DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID())) OR ((pri.[type] = 'G' OR pri.[type] = 'R') AND IS_MEMBER(pri.name)=1)
```

Comment: Could you post the sql code for one of the failing objects?

Comment: Sure:  CREATE VIEW [internal].[current_user_object_permissions]
AS
SELECT     obj.[object_type],
           obj.[object_id],
           obj.[permission_type], 
           obj.[sid],
           obj.[is_role],
           obj.[is_deny]
FROM       [internal].[object_permissions] AS obj INNER JOIN [sys].[database_principals] AS pri
ON obj.[sid] = pri.[sid]
WHERE     
((pri.[type] = 'S' OR pri.[type] = 'U') AND obj.[sid] = USER_SID (DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID()))
OR
((pri.[type] = 'G' OR pri.[type] = 'R') AND IS_MEMBER(pri.name)=1)

Comment: Did you get this code via database import? Or created it yourself?

Comment: This looks like an internal system definition that should not reside in your project?

Answer (score 2):

There is an answer
1. Add Database reference to project 
2. Select system database
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40592/referencing-system-views-in-ssdt
3. Use master master.sys.database_principals in view

Comment: I'm not having any luck with that.   I've tried adding the master.dacpac as a reference as well as adding the master database itself as a reference.   I've also tried including the master database name in the view